# Spring Boot JPA: Could not Extract Result Set Error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to simply persist an object into the database and then retrieve it to check that it has worked. It seems like its connecting to the database but its not finding the table.

I attached all relevant files below.

This is my Data Object:

```
package dataObjects;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="LoadMethod")
public class LoadMethodDO {

    private String mediaId;
    private String activeInd;
    private String loadMethod;
    private String formatMapCd;
    private String detailTransactionReportInd;
    private String accountManaged;

    public LoadMethodDO(){}

    public LoadMethodDO(String mediaId, String loadMethod){
        this.mediaId = mediaId;
        this.loadMethod = loadMethod;
    }
    @Id
    @Column(name="Media_ID", length = 7)
    public String getMediaId() {
        return mediaId;
    }
    public void setMediaId(String mediaId) {
        this.mediaId = mediaId;
    }
    @Column(name="ActInd")
    public String getActiveInd() {
        return activeInd;
    }
    public void setActiveInd(String activeInd) {
        this.activeInd = activeInd;
    }
    @Column(name="LoadMthdCd")
    public String getLoadMethod() {
        return loadMethod;
    }
    public void setLoadMethod(String loadMethod) {
        this.loadMethod = loadMethod;
    }
    @Column(name="FormatMapCd")
    public String getFormatMapCd() {
        return formatMapCd;
    }
    public void setFormatMapCd(String formatter) {
        this.formatMapCd = formatter;
    }
    @Column(name="DtlTransRcdInd")
    public String getDetailTransactionReportInd() {
        return detailTransactionReportInd;
    }
    public void setDetailTransactionReportInd(String detailTransactionReportInd) {
        this.detailTransactionReportInd = detailTransactionReportInd;
    }
    @Column(name="AcctMngdInd")
    public String getAccountManaged() {
        return accountManaged;
    }
    public void setAccountManaged(String accountManaged) {
        this.accountManaged = accountManaged;
    }
}
```

This is my repository file:

```
package repositories;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import dataObjects.LoadMethodDO;

public interface LoadMethodRepository extends CrudRepository<LoadMethodDO, String>{

}
```

This is my Application file that should persist the object:

```
package testApplication;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import dataObjects.LoadMethodDO;
import repositories.LoadMethodRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = LoadMethodRepository.class)
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = LoadMethodDO.class)
@EnableCaching
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(LoadMethodRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {
            // save a couple of customers
            repository.save(new LoadMethodDO("1234567", "1"));
        };
    }
}
```

This is my properties file:

```
#Database Configuration
#db.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
#db.url=jdbc:sqlserver://schqvsqlaod:1433;database=dbMOBClientTemp
#db.username=LOADdev
#db.password=lmtdev02

#Hibernate Configuration
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
#hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.default_schema=dbo

hibernate.packagesToScan=src.repositories.LMClientRepository.java

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.datasource.username=LOADdev
spring.datasource.password=lmtdev01
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://schqvsqlaod:1433;database=dbMOBClientTemp;integratedSecurity=false;
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
#spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.database=dbMOBClientTemp
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none 
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
```

This is my error code:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.6.RELEASE)

2016-08-03 10:27:03.896  INFO 49376 --- [           main] testApplication.Application              : Starting Application on LR90KLWJY with PID 49376 (C:\Users\vincni\git\consumer_load_method\bin started by vincni in C:\Users\vincni\git\consumer_load_method)
2016-08-03 10:27:03.899  INFO 49376 --- [           main] testApplication.Application              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-08-03 10:27:03.963  INFO 49376 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@15bfd87: startup date [Wed Aug 03 10:27:03 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-03 10:27:05.905  INFO 49376 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-08-03 10:27:05.928  INFO 49376 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-08-03 10:27:05.990  INFO 49376 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-08-03 10:27:05.999  INFO 49376 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-08-03 10:27:06.001  INFO 49376 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-08-03 10:27:06.166  INFO 49376 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-08-03 10:27:06.259  WARN 49376 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.d.i.StandardDialectResolver      : HHH000385: Unknown Microsoft SQL Server major version [12] using SQL Server 2000 dialect
2016-08-03 10:27:06.267  INFO 49376 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
2016-08-03 10:27:06.412  INFO 49376 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-08-03 10:27:07.149  INFO 49376 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
Hibernate: select loadmethod0_.media_id as media_id1_0_0_, loadmethod0_.account_managed as account_2_0_0_, loadmethod0_.active_ind as active_i3_0_0_, loadmethod0_.detail_transaction_report_ind as detail_t4_0_0_, loadmethod0_.format_map_cd as format_m5_0_0_, loadmethod0_.load_method as load_met6_0_0_ from load_method loadmethod0_ where loadmethod0_.media_id=?
2016-08-03 10:27:07.228  WARN 49376 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 208, SQLState: S0002
2016-08-03 10:27:07.228 ERROR 49376 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid object name 'load_method'.
2016-08-03 10:27:07.229  INFO 49376 --- [           main] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
2016-08-03 10:27:07.244 ERROR 49376 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:803) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:771) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at testApplication.Application.main(Application.java:25) [bin/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:242) ~[spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225) ~[spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:436) ~[spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at testApplication.Application.lambda$0(Application.java:32) [bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:325) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2149) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:503) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:213) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1106) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2587) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:996) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:306) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:876) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:858) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:863) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1196) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:294) ~[spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:442) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'load_method'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    ... 63 common frames omitted

2016-08-03 10:27:07.250  INFO 49376 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/vincni/git/consumer_load_method/bin/, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.camel/camel-ftp/jars/camel-ftp-2.16.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.camel/camel-core/bundles/camel-core-2.16.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core/jars/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/jars/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.jcraft/jsch/jars/jsch-0.1.53.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/commons-net/commons-net/jars/commons-net-3.3.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/jars/HikariCP-2.4.7.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/jars/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/jars/spring-boot-starter-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/jars/spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-core/jars/spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-context/jars/spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-aop/jars/spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/aopalliance/aopalliance/jars/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-beans/jars/spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-expression/jars/spring-expression-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/jars/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/jars/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/jars/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/jars/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/jars/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/jars/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.yaml/snakeyaml/bundles/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/jars/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/jars/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/jars/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-juli/jars/tomcat-juli-8.0.36.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/jars/spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-tx/jars/spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/jars/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/jars/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging-annotations/jars/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/jars/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/dom4j/dom4j/jars/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/xml-apis/xml-apis/jars/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/jars/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/jars/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.javassist/javassist/bundles/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/antlr/antlr/jars/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.jboss/jandex/jars/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api/jars/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/jars/spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/jars/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-orm/jars/spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-aspects/jars/spring-aspects-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.camel/camel-jpa/jars/camel-jpa-2.10.0.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.camel/camel-spring/bundles/camel-spring-2.10.0.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.poi/poi/jars/poi-3.10.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.5.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/jars/poi-ooxml-3.10.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/jars/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/jars/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/stax/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4/jars/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar, file:/C:/ExternalJARS/ojdbc7.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/eclipselink.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/jpa/javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpars_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/com.sun.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201004141950.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/javax.activation_1.1.0.v201108011116.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/javax.mail_1.4.0.v201005080615.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/javax.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201105210648.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/javax.xml.stream_1.0.1.v201004272200.jar]
2016-08-03 10:27:07.250  INFO 49376 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)


2016-08-03 10:27:07.251  INFO 49376 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@15bfd87: startup date [Wed Aug 03 10:27:03 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-03 10:27:07.256  INFO 49376 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2016-08-03 10:27:07.257  INFO 49376 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Comment: `Invalid object name 'load_method'.` So where is that coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that 'load_method' table exists in your database? You have commented out schema creation so there is possibility that there is no such table there or you have created it with wrong name like 'LoadMethod' but

```
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

changed it to 'load_method'.

Have you tried to execute query:

```
select loadmethod0_.media_id as media_id1_0_0_,
 loadmethod0_.account_managed as account_2_0_0_,
 loadmethod0_.active_ind as active_i3_0_0_,
 loadmethod0_.detail_transaction_report_ind as detail_t4_0_0_, 
 loadmethod0_.format_map_cd as format_m5_0_0_, 
 loadmethod0_.load_method as load_met6_0_0_ from load_method 
 loadmethod0_ where loadmethod0_.media_id=?
```

Comment: Steered me in the right direction. I changed the properties line to this `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy` and it worked. The one you suggested still changed my table name to underscore delimited for some reason.

Comment: I wrote that ImprovedNamingStrategy changes names to ones with underscores. Anyway, I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're using the correct SQL Dialect in your application.properties/application.yml file.

In my case, I'm using a yml application.yml file.

```
spring:
  jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect
```